# Rake test expects for the table name defined as model name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an MS SQL db table (`dbo.MEXICAN_FLOWERS`), used by a model `Flower`. In order to write test cases, I wrote a dummy migration file for that model, and then modified the migration file with the column names that the db has, and ran:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Also I tried:

```
$RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

and verified that everything looks great. When I try to do:

```
$ rake test
```

it raises an error such that a table with flowers is not found:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: flower: DELETE FROM “flower”
```

Why is this happening?

I also ran:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run tests, Rails doesn't look at your regular database. Instead, it looks at your ***fixtures***.

You need to write fake data in test/fixtures/flowers.

Cheers!

Comment: I already have fixtures like this: /test/fixtures/flower.yml file. Is it wrong?

Comment: I can tell you that all of my fixture files are plural: scores.yml, seminars.yml, users.yml, etc. Maybe that has something to do with it?